# Extension of definition measurable function

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

[image]

This is from Rudin's RCA book. I read this paragraph few times with big aatention and have some questions:

$1)$ Why Rudin's enlarges the definition in above manner?

$2)$ He wrote that domain of $f$ is $E$ then $f^{-1}(V)\subset E$ hence $f^{-1}(V)\cap E=f^{-1}(V)$. Am I right?

$3)$ If we define $f(x)=0$ on $E^c$ why we obtain measurable function in the old sense?

$4)$ If our measure is complete why we can define $f$ on $E^c$ in a arbitrary manner and we still get a measurable function?

Can anyone explain these questions please?

Comment: I have problems with this too. "... a function defined on a set $E$...". That could mean that $f$ has $E$ as domain, and in that case it is weird to mention $f^{-1}(V)\cap E$. This because of what you observed in 2). Another possibility is that "defined on $E$" must not be read as if $E$ is a subset of the codomain of $f$. But then what is the codomain of $f$? Maybe $X$, but then more caution is needed by proceding with defining $f$ on $E^c$ by e.g. $f(x)=0$. This because it allready *is defined* there.

Comment: Comment on former comment: the word "not" must be left out in the sentence "must not be read as if $E$ is a subset.." Sorry for confusion.